# Convert NSTextCheckingResult addressComponents dictionary to string with DataDetector in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Apples `NSDataDetector` can detect a variety of things such as addresses, dates and urls as `NSTextCheckingResults`. For addresses, it captures the information in a dictionary with a lot of keys representing elements of the address such as address, city, state and zipcode.  [Here are the various keys.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstextcheckingresult/keys_for_address_components?language=objc)

My problem is that I am weak on using dictionaries and can't figure out syntax to convert the dictionary back into a regular string.  I need a string so I can feed it into a natural language query for maps.

Can anyone suggest the syntax to convert the dictionary into a string.

Here is the code I am using to detect the dictionary.

```
 NSDictionary* addrDict= nil;
    NSString *addr = nil;
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:(NSTextCheckingTypes)NSTextCheckingTypeAddress error:&error];

    NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:string
                                         options:0
                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    NSLocale* currentLoc = [NSLocale currentLocale];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeAddress) {

            addrDict = [match addressComponents];
//How do I convert this dictionary back into a string that says something like 
         Starbucks 123 Main Street Mountain View CA 94103  
        }

    }
```

Comment: `NSRange addressMatchRange = [match range]; NSString *matchString = [string substringWithRange:addressMatchRange];`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSTextCheckingResult` has a property `range` that you can use:

This should do the trick:

```
NSRange addressMatchRange = [match range];
NSString *matchString = [string substringWithRange:addressMatchRange];
```

If you want to retrieve if from the dictionary:
`addrDict[NSTextCheckingZIPKey]` will give you `94103`, `addrDict[NSTextCheckingStateKey]` will give you `CA`, etc, and you have to reconstruct it, but the order is up to you then.